# Rails Active Support Instrumentation Mongoid db runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, instrumentation

db_runtime in payload for process_action.action_controller is 0 when I am using Mongoid. Is there a way to support Mongoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was added in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4631 and will be available in the next patch releases of 6.4 and 7.0. In the meantime you could try using the respective stable branch (6.4.0-stable or 7.0.0-stable) or apply the PR linked from the ticket.